# Python Using For Loop to find even numbers in a list and then multiply them by 2

Tags: python, for-loop

So I've got a script that needs to read the numbers in a list and the tell me which of those numbers is odd and which ones are even AND if the number is even I need it to be multiplied 1 and then multiplied by 2. I've gotten quite close, but I can't seem to figure out where I'm making my mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
for n in numbers:
    if n%2 == 0:
        print(n,'is an even number.')
        for n in range(2,5,2):
            product = n
            print('Multiplying by 1 gives',product)
            product = product*2
            print('Multiplying by 2 gives', product)
    else:
        print(n,'is an odd number.')
```

I'm getting the following output:

> 1 is an odd number.
>   2 is an even number.
>   Multiplying by 1 gives 2
>   Multiplying by 2 gives 4
>   Multiplying by 1 gives 4
>   Multiplying by 2 gives 8
>   3 is an odd number.
>   4 is an even number.
>   Multiplying by 1 gives 2
>   Multiplying by 2 gives 4
>   Multiplying by 1 gives 4
>   Multiplying by 2 gives 8
>   5 is an odd number.

Whereas my desired output should look like:

> 1 is an odd number.
>   2 is an even number.
>   Multiplying by 1 gives 2
>   Multiplying by 2 gives 4
>   3 is an odd number.
>   4 is an even number.
>   Multiplying by 1 gives 4
>   Multiplying by 2 gives 8
>   5 is an odd number.

Comment: Simply delete the second `for` line. It serves no purpose and modifies the original `n` variable.

Comment: What's the point of multiplying a number by 1?

Comment: `I need it to be multiplied 1 ` Why? Multiplying a number by 1 has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Simply removing `for n in range(2,5,2):` for loop will give you the desired result, it was overriding the value of `n`, thus giving you the wrong results.

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for n in numbers:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        print(n, 'is an even number.')
        product = n
        print('Multiplying by 1 gives', product)
        product = product*2
        print('Multiplying by 2 gives', product)
    else:
        print(n, 'is an odd number.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the second for-loop can be omitted. Try this:

```
for n in numbers:
    if n%2 == 0:
        print(n,'is an even number.\nMultuplying',n,'by 1 
        gives',n,'\nMultiplying',n,'by 2 gives',n*2)

    else:
        print(n,'is an odd number.')
```